# Cutting down two data sets to the same size

Tags: python

I have two data sets: Temperature A over Time, and Temperature B over Time. They are both over the same time interval. The problem is that one set has 375,638 values and the other one 66,933. The time between each data point in both A and B vary from 5 seconds to 60 seconds.

I would like to cut down data set A to the same size as B, by taking the average value for each second or possibly linear interpolation, but I am not sure how to do this. The function I am writing is getting rather convoluted and confusing with several nested loops, so I am wondering if there is some easy way to do this that I am overlooking.

Thanks

Comment: you need to provide the data example and the code which you are tryingto do

Comment: edit the question with some visuals let people see what you are trying and an example of what the data sets look like

Answer (score 0):

You can use **split()** function from numpy:

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20, 4), columns=list('abcd'))
df1, df2 = np.split(df, [int(len(df)/2)], axis=0)
```

out df

```
a   b   c   d
0   0.175034    0.491546    0.214332    0.551543
1   0.360353    0.529040    0.949357    0.990295
2   0.475146    0.684860    0.252388    0.319754
3   0.296353    0.668867    0.806810    0.303479
4   0.125018    0.195096    0.470490    0.535244
5   0.279616    0.888702    0.925141    0.142643
6   0.713421    0.762474    0.332148    0.546850
7   0.908884    0.247675    0.008861    0.291648
8   0.002747    0.513682    0.609479    0.215230
9   0.789802    0.270530    0.390524    0.356701
10  0.621201    0.502328    0.458017    0.342552
11  0.983250    0.302190    0.439821    0.527750
12  0.348954    0.191272    0.402686    0.692401
13  0.623846    0.846459    0.376363    0.263270
14  0.786151    0.113710    0.585870    0.633940
15  0.394097    0.452079    0.303508    0.796536
16  0.256991    0.829933    0.386324    0.994061
17  0.163573    0.158677    0.156570    0.641327
18  0.255664    0.855975    0.217292    0.274872
19  0.938094    0.145893    0.353586    0.740469
```

out df1

```
a   b   c   d
0   0.175034    0.491546    0.214332    0.551543
1   0.360353    0.529040    0.949357    0.990295
2   0.475146    0.684860    0.252388    0.319754
3   0.296353    0.668867    0.806810    0.303479
4   0.125018    0.195096    0.470490    0.535244
5   0.279616    0.888702    0.925141    0.142643
6   0.713421    0.762474    0.332148    0.546850
7   0.908884    0.247675    0.008861    0.291648
8   0.002747    0.513682    0.609479    0.215230
9   0.789802    0.270530    0.390524    0.356701
```

out df2

```
a   b   c   d
10  0.621201    0.502328    0.458017    0.342552
11  0.983250    0.302190    0.439821    0.527750
12  0.348954    0.191272    0.402686    0.692401
13  0.623846    0.846459    0.376363    0.263270
14  0.786151    0.113710    0.585870    0.633940
15  0.394097    0.452079    0.303508    0.796536
16  0.256991    0.829933    0.386324    0.994061
17  0.163573    0.158677    0.156570    0.641327
18  0.255664    0.855975    0.217292    0.274872
19  0.938094    0.145893    0.353586    0.740469
```

Answer (score 0):

You could random sample 66,933 values from set A:

```
random.sample(SetB, len(setA))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas interpolation on both of your sets and then select the values at specific time values (or frequencies) from both of them. It is better than taking the average if you know that the temperature in your specific problem is most likely to vary linearly.

```
a = [(time1, value1) , (time2, value2) , .....]  # 375638 values
b = [(TIME1, VALUE1) , (TIME2, VALUE2) , .....]  # 66933  values

da       = pd.DataFrame( a , columns = ['times', 'values']).set_index('times')
db       = pd.DataFrame( b , columns = ['TIMES', 'VALUES']).set_index('TIMES')

da2      = pd.Series(da['values'], index = da.index)
db2      = pd.Series(db['VALUES'], index = db.index)

interpol_a = da2.resample('S').interpolate(method='linear') # 'S' for interpolation in seconds
interpol_b = db2.resample('S').interpolate(method='linear')

interp_values_a = interpol_a.loc['index']
interp_values_b = interpol_b.loc['index'] # 'index' is the index at which you want the interpolated
                                          #  values which in your case will be the time instant or
                                          #  you can use a list of instants using proper indexing 


# Feed same time instants to both interpol.loc[] methods to get temperature values at same instants for both datasets
```

Comment: Agreed that `pandas.DataFrame.resample` is what you should be looking at for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> by taking the average value for each second or possibly linear interpolation, but I am not sure how to do this

Assuming those are not sets, but lists sorted by time, and that you don't want any external library (like the already suggested Pandas), quick code of a general idea:

```
current_time_bound = start_time
time_interval = 1
current_index = 0
counter = 0
sum = 0
while current_index < len(your_list):
    if your_list[current_index].time < current_time_bound:
        counter+=1
        sum+=your_list[current_index].value
        current_index+=1
    else:
        average = sum/counter #remember to check the counter because it might be 0
        #and append the average to the new list
        counter=0 #reset variables for the next group
        sum=0
        current_time_bound+=time_interval #move the time forward
```

Of course time would need to be in whatever format you use and added/compared in that format as well. It's just a general idea.

Such things can probably be done in a purely functional manner (I remember seeing something similar done in Scala) but it might be confusing.